# Disable pipeline for every commit in Gitlab and only run it on open merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

The CI pipeline runs on every commit in my Gitlab repository at work. Is there way to disable that and only run the CI pipeline on an open merge request to the master branch?

Answer (score 47):

There is currently no configuration option to do that. Here are some things that can be used to "disable" a pipeline build.

- Adding `[ci skip]` inside the commit message will not trigger a pipeline on push.
- Using `except` and `only` options on all jobs inside the pipeline. To avoid duplication in this case, you can use [Anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors).

**Update: GitLab 11.7**

When pushing to GitLab you can skip triggering a pipeline by passing ci.skip option to the push command: `git push -o ci.skip`

Answer (score 24):

Update in 2020 because solution with `only` and `except` are candidates for deprecation : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Still in `.gitlab-ci.yml` you should use now `rules` : See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

I simply set this rule on my build job and the job is "blocked" and wait a manual trigger from the UI.

```
 rules:
   - when: manual
```

Note that we can create more advanced rules with conditions to trigger for exemple if we see a git tag.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#exclude-jobs-with-rules-from-certain-pipelines

Comment: Should be noted that this ccreates a manual job, that does not run immediately but requires to click a button on the GitLab UI to run. The question asked for a change to the type of trigger, from a commit to only on an open merge request. I think you’d want to do something like the [example given](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines) `if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"` etc.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, but only if you set it on each job within the pipeline.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

```
job:
  script: echo 'test'
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

That job will only run on commits that are part of a merge request, rather than every push of a commit to a branch. If you set every job to this setting then the pipeline will never run.

Comment: This looks like the actual good answer ... Can't we add some generic ``rules`` to prevent all the CI to run ?

Comment: I don't think you can? You're better off setting some generic rules and using the yaml anchor syntax to include that in the rules for every job. Gitlab will evaluate each single job, rather than the entire pipeline as whole so you can't just set one generic rule.

Answer (score 11):

You could add something like this in the beginning of your .gitlab-ci.yaml

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
```

For more info look at [Merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can just add `[ci skip]` to the commit message and builds will be skipped

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14499

Answer (score 1):

No. (Not yet !)
You can follow the expected feature development here.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23902

However, you can automatically trigger pipelines using "maofr"'s code

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23902#note_88958643

Answer (score 0):

For **merge** we can use this guide [#onlyrefs--exceptrefs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs)

> merge_requests

> For pipelines created when a merge request is created or updated. Enables merge request pipelines, merged results pipelines, and merge trains.

and for generally triggering pipeline we can use `only:` and `variables:` together:

```
  script:
    - . diff.sh $SMS_MESSAGE
  only:
    variables:
      - $ACTION == "diff"
```

then triggering it is easy using `curl`:

```
curl -X POST \
    -F token=$TOKEN \     # your token
    -F ref=$REF_NAME \    # branch name
    -F "variables[ACTION]=diff" \   # variable 
    https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/0/trigger/pipeline # your project endpoint
```

This part `variables[ACTION]=diff` will assign **diff** into **ACTION** and it will apply to `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `only:` section.

Answer (score 0):

```
job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Do your build here"
  except:
    - pushes
```

Use `except` `pushes` to stop create a new pipeline on every pushed commits. For reference check [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022 :**
According to the documention of Gitlab on:   https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when

you can use `when: manual` to run the job only when triggered manually.

Example:

```
deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - make deploy
  when: manual
```

You don't need also `rules` for that.