# Auto run GitLab pipeline only after MR is raised

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

To keep things short, these are the requirements for workflow of a GitLab CI/CD pipeline

1. Pipeline should automatically run on MR create event
2. Pipeline should **not** run for any commit/push before or after MR is created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable pipeline for every commit in Gitlab and only run it on open merge request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431537/disable-pipeline-for-every-commit-in-gitlab-and-only-run-it-on-open-merge-reques)

Answer (score -1):

In order enable pipeline for merge requests for all jobs, you can make use of `workflow:rules`.

Here is an example:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID    # Execute jobs in merge request context

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./build

test:
  stage: test
  script: ./test
```

Comment: This does not fulfil the requirements.
This runs pipeline for every commit after MR is raised.
Req -> Pipeline should only run once after MR is raised and NOT run automatically for subsequent commits/pushes