# How to disable auto pipelines in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Since gitlab limited free tier minutes on gitlab CI/CD. I would like to disable auto start for my pipeline after commit.

**I would like to run pipeline only manually by click in gitlab interface**.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable pipeline for every commit in Gitlab and only run it on open merge request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431537/disable-pipeline-for-every-commit-in-gitlab-and-only-run-it-on-open-merge-reques)

Answer (score 39):

You can disable the Gitlab CI/CD Pipelines in project by following steps:

1. Go to Project's **Settings >> General >> Visibility, project features, permissions**
2. Expand the **Repository** section
3. Enable or Disable the **CI/CD** toggle
4. Then, click on **Save Changes**

You can verify the same, the CI/CD option has been disappeared from left-hand side panel.

[image]

---

---

**I have now updated the answer with reference to question:**

Adding `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` inside the commit message will not trigger a pipeline on push.

More reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skip-pipeline

Comment: He asked for a way to deactivate automatic pipeline starts but to keep the ability to start the pipeline manually

Comment: The setting has moved and can be found under `Settings > General > CI/CD`.

Comment: @AlexanderEble can you share which option it is? I can't see the same options under `CI/CD`

Comment: @scientific_explorer Be aware that is not `Settings > CI/CD` but `Settings > General > CI/CD`.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderEble to suggest the edits.

Answer (score 17):

You can add the following code to your .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

More reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#workflow
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: It has to the answer to the question! Thanks Lucas!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to clarify a bit Lucas Lucas Hillesheim (@lucas-hillesheim) answer.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

CI/CD can be triggered by different events. Gitlab suggests to use `workflow` keyword to control such behaviour. `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` leads to run pipeline only when user pushes button on web page. All other events such as `push`, `merge_request_event` and other will not lead to running pipeline.

Indeed, it the best way to prevent auto CI/CD running, because in cases when I need to use `only`/`except` for specific jobs - are just workarounds. Firstly, because the question is to how to not run CI/CD every time, but with job rules, the pipeline itself is run anyway. Secondly, if I have many jobs with complex `needs` between them - using more conditions just for job starting is a nightmare. Thirdly, it still leads to flooding unfinished/canceled pipelines on pipeline webpage.