# Instruct gitlab ci to run only certain stages for a commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Just like `git push -o ci.skip` [can be used to skip all stages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023640/1412255), is it possible to also just as easily specify a whitelist of stages to run while pushing?

Currently I have to manually go to gitlab UI after a push and skip the stages that I don't want running. I also have to track stage dependencies manually while doing this.

Can this be done more easily?

Answer (score 2):

You can set CICD variables with git push options. Therefore, you can use such variables to set whether a job runs or not using `only:variables`/`except:variables` or `rules:`

For example:

```yaml
my_job:
  rules:
    - if: $MY_VARIABLE_NEVER
      when: never
    - if: $MY_VARIABLE_ALWAYS
      when: always
    - when: on_success
  # ...
```

Then you can use the push option to set the variables in your rules:

```sh
# excludes my_job from the pipeline
git push -o ci.variable="MY_VARIABLE_NEVER=true"
```

This can't be applied for an entire stage directly, but you can apply the applicable `only:`/`except:` or `rules:` for each job in the stage you want to control.